# how to get form from javascript to vb asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

how to get form from javascript to vb asp.net?

i am creating a form in javascript and sending it to vb asp.net side.

How to get javascript form value in vb asp.net?

right now getclienttoken prints nothing. there is no value inside that variable.

vb asp.net code

```
 Protected Sub Page_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim nvc As NameValueCollection = Request.Form
            Dim GetClientToken As String = nvc("token")
            Label1.Text = "flag1" & GetClientToken
        End If
    End Sub
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
    form.submit();
    ...
</script>
```

html code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" />
                    <div class="group">
                      <label>
                        <span>Card number</span>
                        <div id="card-number-element" class="field"></div>
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <span>Expiry date</span>
                        <div id="card-expiry-element" class="field"></div>
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <span>CVC</span>
                        <div id="card-cvc-element" class="field"></div>
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <span>Postal code</span>
                        <input id="postal-code" name="postal_code" class="field" placeholder="90210" />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Pay</button>
```

Comment: Looks like you missing a <form> element.

Comment: vb asp.net coming with default form tags so i do want nested forms

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

- could be a missing value in `result.token.id`;
- could be an issue in when or how the js is triggered;
- could be (most likely) `If Not IsPostBack Then` should be removed -- code in this block will only be fired on first load and not after that.

Comment: javascript token.id does print in alert

Comment: rather than sumbitting form? can't i just use hiddenfield? but would that be save bc i do not want anyone knowing this token.id